# Derive the Power Spectral Density of output process

Tags: power, signal, signal-processing, signal-theory, noise-spectral-density

Derive the Power Spectral Density of output process. This question is from undergraduate physics course. Please help! I do not even know where to begin!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The system depicted is linear and time-invariant, which means you can treat it as a filter. In other words, the PSD of the output is the PSD of the input multiplied by the frequency response of the filter.

One way to get the frequency response of the filter is to take the Fourier Transform of its impulse response.

Hint to verify that you're on the right track: When you add (or subtract) a time-delayed copy of a signal to itself, you get what's commonly called a "comb filter".

Comment: And what is the impulse response?

Comment: Well, if you don't know what an impulse response is, then this question is probably a bit beyond your current level of skill, and that makes it too broad to answer here.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid it is, but I'm trying very hard. is the impulse response dv? So the answer is  S_u F[dv] ? where F is the fourier transform